# Rewriting "assertTrue" into "assertThat" in JUnit?

Tags: junit, hamcrest

```
List<String> list1 = getListOne();
List<String> list2 = getListTwo();
```

Given the code above, I want to use a JUnit `assertThat()` statement to assert that either `list1` is empty or that `list1` contains all the elements of `list2`. The `assertTrue` equivalent of this is:

`assertTrue(list1.isEmpty() || list1.containsAll(list2))`.

How to formulate this into an `assertThat` statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
// Imports
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.either;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsEmptyIterable.emptyIterableOf;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining.hasItems;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

// First solution
assertThat(list1,
    either(emptyIterableOf(String.class))
    .or(hasItems(list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]))));

// Second solution, this will work ONLY IF both lists have items in the same order.
assertThat(list1,
    either(emptyIterableOf(String.class))
        .or(is((Iterable<String>) list2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use Hamcrest Matchers but it seems very simple for your case:

```
assertThat("Custom Error message", list1.isEmpty() || list1.containsAll(list2));
```

For your scenario seems a lot easier use a boolean condition than a matcher. And the [only assertion that accepts a boolean condition](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/hamcrest-java-1.3/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.java) is this one that forces you to use an error message.

Comment: Your solution does not work wth JUnit's `Assert.assertThat` but rather only with `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat`.

Comment: "The only assertion that accepts a boolean condition is this one that forces you to use an error message"? How about `assertThat(value, is(true))`?